# c# regex get only negative numbers in string

Tags: c#, regex, string

So my task is to choose only **negative numbers** in my string. However, there is a big problem. My string constists of different minuses (some for negative numbers, some for subtracting).

My idea is to get negative numbers, if there are **no more digits before the minus**.
My regex pattern:

```
(\d{0}-)?\d+
```

The same pattern that doesn't work as I thought:

```
((?!\d)-)?\d+
```

---

And I test this pattern on this text:

```
-1 2 (33-44)
```

My expection: **-1 2 33 44**

Result: **-1 2 33 -44**

As you can see the last minus is used for subtracting, it doesn't mean a negative number.

Comment: It's not regex so I'm not posting it as an answer, but since I'm crap at regex I would use this: `myStr.Split(' ').Where(x => x.ToCharArray()[0] == '-').ToList();` Just goes to show there's more than one way to skin a cat!

Comment: What you need is to parse this to an AST, something that understands that the binary subtraction operator and the unary negative operator are different even though they use the same symbol.

Comment: I do have a question though: should any 'numbers' that involve math be evaluated to see if the result is negative?

Comment: Your condition isn't specific enough for your purpose. Unless you require parenthesis, and even then it's hard, you cannot be sure that it's unary minus. If your example in order 2 -1 (33 -44), then you also couldn't be sure if those are 2 and -1 or 2-1. @madreflection I'm not sure AST is viable since this doesn't look like complete expression...

Comment: @nemanja OP would have to create a parser/lexer for this specific grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get your expected result by using [Negative Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`?<!`), checking if there are one or more numbers ahead of the `-`:

```
(?<!\d+)-?\d+
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/AAJjTV/2)

In order to just match the negative numbers in your string, you'd need to make the `-` required:

```
(?<!\d)-\d+
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/AAJjTV/3)

Comment: You have updated your answer to exactly the same a my answer.

Comment: @Thefourthbird That's right. When i answered it yesterday evening i didn't read his question correctly and only provided the first part of my current answer. When i checked back on it a few minutes ago i saw your answer, then re-read OP's question and updated my answer as well. I understand that you might take this as a copy-cat attempt, but considering i answered the question 13h before you already and the only difference i made to my orginal answer, was a removed `?` -  i think it's fine.

Comment: So yeah. That's what I need! Sorry that I couldn't answer earlier.